# ASP.net Core: dynamically selecting the controller action to invoke

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0, asp.net-core-6.0

I have an `ASP.net Core 6` web application where I have two controller actions similar to this:

```
[Route("auth")]
[ApiController]
public class AuthController: ControllerBase {
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("login/credentials")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> LoginWithCredentials(...)
    {
      //...
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("login/token")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> LoginWithToken(...)
    {
      //...
    }
}
```

What I would like to do is having any requests that is made towards:

```
/auth/login
```

to actually be forwarded to either `LoginWithCredentials()` or `LoginWithToken()` depending on a server-side configuration.

In other words, I would like to dynamically chose the controller action for any request that matches a certain route.

Is this possible? If so, how can I do this?

NOTE: I've tried using a `DynamicRouteValueTransformer` but it doesn't seem to do what I want, it can change the values of route parameters but not change the controller action that is invoked (either that or I'm not using it correctly, please enlighten me if that's the case)

ADDITIONAL NOTE: I see people asking why I don't just use a single action with an if statement inside. The reason is that one of the two actions has a custom `TypeFilterAttribute` that I've omitted from the example for brevity. Thus, I can't just merge the two into one because then either the one that needs the attribute would not have it or vice-versa the one that doesn't need it would have it. And I can't change the source code of this custom filter either to "neuter" it when it is not needed, because it comes from a library that I'm not authorized to modify.

Comment: Why not a single controller action with an if statement?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft: good question. It's the first thing I thought of, but (I've omitted this for simplicity) one of the two methods has a custom `TypeFilterAttribute`, so I can't just merge them into one because either the one that needs the attribute would not have or the one that doesn't need it would have it...

Comment: then is it possible to create an API which read the server configuration then redirect to one of your action method?

Comment: @TinyWang: that is exactly what I'm doing at the moment, I was wondering if there was a way that didn't require knowledge on the client side.

Comment: sorry I didnt know that kind of way ... and I'm afraid it doesn't exist.